# javascript local storage visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, local-storage

I've created a library to make local storage act more like a DB. I'm using Visual Studio to test this library out and it works great, but when debugging from Visual Studio once I stop debugging the local storage isn't persistent through another run from Visual Studio (I have VS using IE 10 to launch the page).

**Is there any way to make it persistent when doing this from Visual Studio so I can better test my apps that use it?**

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the simple solution is to set up an IIS instance instead of using the virtual server it creates. In the project properties point to that instance and tell it not to spin up the application on every debug.

It also makes debugging faster :-) because you can keep the browser window open where your running and just refresh the page. (Remember to force clear the cache though)